# Android: Communication and coordination between UI-thread and other thread

Tags: android, multithreading, android-activity, android-asynctask

I'm using this AsyncTask for calling the skype page [https://login.skype.com/json/validator?new_username=username](https://login.skype.com/json/validator?new_username=myusername) for understand if a certain skype contact already exsists.

```
public class SkypeValidateUserTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{

protected String doInBackground(String...urls){
    String response = "";
    for(String url:urls){
        DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
        try{
            HttpResponse execute = client.execute(httpGet);
            InputStream content = execute.getEntity().getContent();

            BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(content));

            String s="";
            while((s=buffer.readLine()) != null){
                response+=s;
            }
        }catch(Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return response;
}

public void onPostExecute(String result){
    String status="";
    try{    
        JSONObject obj=new JSONObject(result);
        status=obj.getString("status");
    }catch(Exception ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    //Log.i("RISULTATO: ","STATO: "+status);

}
}
```

The main activity call this task for getting skype validation user result. The code is:

```
String skype = "name.surname.example";  

if(!skype.equalsIgnoreCase("")){
            // check if the skype contact exists
            SkypeValidateUserTask task = new SkypeValidateUserTask();
            task.execute(new String[] {"https://login.skype.com/json/validator?new_username="+skype});  

                // here I need to obtain the result of the thread

        }
```

My problems are:

1. I need to get the result of the task (the String `status`) in the main activity.
2. After the `task.execute` call, the next code in main activity is executed without wait for result returned from asynctask.

Comment: using get will block the UI Thread see the answer I have provided

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is dengerious to use get() method to get the result from async task because It blocks the UI Thread.
use This Thread where I provided a reusable solution[Callback mechanism to get result from async thread without blocking UI Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14253421/how-one-interface-can-be-used-for-different-background-android-tasks/14376233#14376233)

I have implemented that with the help of [lapslaz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1342413/laplasz)

```
public JsonData(YourActivityClass activity) 
{
    this.activity=activity;
    mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(activity);

}
protected void onPostExecute(String jsondata) {
    if (mProgressDialog != null || mProgressDialog.isShowing()){
        mProgressDialog.dismiss();
    }
    if(jsondata!=null) {
        activity.yourcallback(jsondata)
    }

}

And define the yourcallback() in YourActivityClass

private void yourcallback(String data) {
    jsonRecordsData=data;
    showRecordsFromJson();

}
```

Comment: And what changes if I have a Dialog instead of Activity?

Comment: @Joseph82 Your dialog is part of the activity so can use it in your dialog also...

Comment: Ok, I will try. But what is JsonData ? The constructor of my AsyncTask?

Comment: I have provided the complete code in the link please check once. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14253421/how-one-interface-can-be-used-for-different-background-android-tasks/14376233#14376233

Answer (score 1):

Start your AsyncTask on the main thread. In the **preExecute** method of the AsyncTask, you can start a ProgressDialog to indicate to the user that you're doing something that takes a few seconds. Use **doInBackground** to perform the long-running task (checking for valid Skype username, in your case). When it is complete, **onPostExecute** will be called. Since this runs on the UI thread, you can handle the result and perform further actions depending on it. Don't forget to close the ProgressDialog in onPostExecute.

Comment: Ok, but how can I pass the String status from my background Task to UI-Thread? The onPostExecute can't access to my main activity cause is in another class (SkypeValidateUserTask )

Comment: My AsyncTask can't view Progress dialog created in main activity. so I can't call dialog.dismiss();

Comment: There are several ways you could handle that - Refactor the code to be run after SkypeValidateUserTask into the onPostExecute itself, or notify your activity of the result in onPostExecute.

Comment: As for the ProgressDialog, you could just create it in onPreExecute!

Comment: I trid using dialog.show in  onPreExecute and dialog.dismiss onPostExecute, but my UI-Thread does not stop its execution.

Comment: The UI thread will NOT stop its execution. Use ProgressDialog.show(...) in onPreExecute and hold on to the object in a field of the AsyncTask and dismiss it in onPostExecute

Answer (score 0):

That's why asyncTask is here. You can not make a blocking function call in UI thread because that will make your app unresponsive.

Answer (score 0):

**OnPostExcute**  Method is called on the **UI/Main** thread. you need to move your logic there to continue analyzing the result.

Comment: @Joseph82 That is unachievable. You must process the result later when  `onPostExcute` is called

Comment: You don't have to wait for it, because onPost will actually be excuted in the main thread , so why would you wait, just move your logic to onPost excute

Answer (score 0):

If your `AsyncTask` is an inner class of your main activity then you can just call a function in the main activity and pass it the `result`

Since it looks like it isn't, you can create constructor in your `Async` and pass it the `Context` from your main activity so you can pass the variable back to main activity

Also, the purpose of the `AyncTask` is to not block your `UI` thread, put your logic in a separate function that the `AsyncTask` will call

Comment: Using a non-static inner AsyncTask is a bad idea because it can lead to memory leaks in case of configuration changes (screen orientation, keyboard etc). Holding on to the Activity in the AsyncTask can again lead to the Activity instance being leaked. Refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3357477/is-asynctask-really-conceptually-flawed-or-am-i-just-missing-something

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement a call-back mechanism in your AsyncTask. So instead of this:

```
task.execute(...);
// use results of task
```

Your structure should be:

```
    task.execute(...);
    // go do something else while task has a chance to execute

public void statusAvailable(String status) {
    // use results of task
}
```

and in `onPostExecute`:

```
public void onPostExecute(String result) {
    . . .
    status=obj.getString("status");
    activity.statusAvailable(status);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Getting the result out of the AsyncTask is easy . . . just the Google docs don't make it clear how to do it. Here's a quick run down.

```
task.execute(params);
```

will start the AsyncTask and pass to the `doInBackground` method whatever parameters you include. Once `doInBackground` finishes, it passes the result of its functions to `onPostExecute`. One would think that `onPostExecute` would be able to just return whatever you sent it. It doesn't. To get the result of `doInBackground`, which was sent to `onPostExecute` you need to call

```
task.get();
```

the `.get()` method automaticlly waits until the task has completed execution and then returns whatever the result of `onPostExecute` is back to the UI thread. You can assign the result to whatever variable you want and use normally after that - for example

```
JSONObject skypeStuff = task.get()
```

Put another way - just like the AsynTask does not start on it's own, it does not return on its own. The same way you need to `.execute()` from the UI thread, you need to call `.get()` from the UI thread to extract the result of the task.

Comment: @Rarw using get will block the UI Thread see the answer I have provided

Comment: Yes. This is a dangerous thing to do, and will cause an ANR