# Receiving Null while Parsing JSON

Tags: java, android, json, parsing, httpresponse

Here is the response that I am receiving from my REST service from a GET Request:

```
{
  "type": "usersTable",
  "employeeId": 1,
  "employeeName": "Andrew Watson",
  "userPin": "705207"
}
```

I am trying to retrieve the `userPin` value from the JSON.

Here is the code I have attempted:

```
if (con.getResponseCode() == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK 
           || con.getResponseCode() == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_ACCEPTED ) {
    String line;
    BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
    while ((line=br.readLine()) != null) {
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(br.toString());
        userPinRetrieved = String.valueOf(json.getInt("userPin"));
    }
}
```

Can anyone see why I am getting a Null Pointer?

Comment: Can you share the error log with us?

Comment: Why `br.toString()` ?

Comment: @Lokesh I have seen this way used in other examples from this site.. should I be using something else?

Comment: Full crash log please.

Comment: @ThumChoonTat its not giving an error it is just getting null value

Comment: `json.getInt` on a String? Your `userPin` is a String not an int.

Comment: is it weird that it is receiving null at runtime but receiving the correct value at debug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not tested this one yet. But I think the problem is `userPin` is string not an integer value.

```
 if (con.getResponseCode() == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK 
               || con.getResponseCode() == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_ACCEPTED ) {
        String line;
        BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
        while ((line=br.readLine()) != null) {
            JSONObject json = new JSONObject(br.toString()); 
            if(json.getString("userPin") == null) {
               //do something here or define the default value
            }else {
                userPinRetrieved = json.getString("userPin");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: is it weird that it is receiving null at runtime but receiving the correct value at debug? @Lokesh

Comment: can you check that your object's property "userPin" has got the pin value ?

Comment: @AndroidBeginner2018 I have update my answer. You can define a default value to the userPinRetrieved or do something else, if it's null. It should not  throw exception this time

Comment: yes it is getting the correct pin value at debug mode. Although when I actually run the program it is getting null. very strange.

Comment: @AndroidBeginner2018 Can you try the updated answer ? And can you include the code why is it getting null ? I think the data you are receiving is having null values. If that is the case then you can avoid it using the updated answer

Comment: this was my problem: see also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50642036/asynctask-not-returning-result-quick-enough-to-main-thread

Comment: you may also like this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15635436/returning-data-from-asynctask-without-blocking-ui/15635493?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa