# Android: Implementing a reusable HTTP Async Method

Tags: android, post, methods, android-asynctask, code-reuse

I've been searching but I do not find any implementation of a method that allows to make an HTTP post request receiving both the URL and the data as parameters of the function.

I mean, all the samples I've found are tailored for a specific set of parameters and what I need is to get in the AsyncTask method a URL and an array with the data, but how to pass the url (string) parameter and the post data (array) parameter?

Any help or link will be appreciated.

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14253421/how-one-interface-can-be-used-for-different-background-android-tasks/14376233#14376233

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use the following pattern for similar cases:

```
import java.util.List;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import android.os.AsyncTask;

public class AsyncHttpPostTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {

    private List<NameValuePair> httpPostParams;
    private String postHref;
    private String someOtherValue;

    public AsyncHttpPostTask(final String postHref, final List<NameValuePair> httpPostParams, final String someOtherValue) {
        super();
        this.postHref = postHref;
        this.httpPostParams = httpPostParams;
        this.someOtherValue = someOtherValue;
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(final Void... params) {
        // Use httpPostParams (or any other values you supplied to a constructor) in your actual Http post here
        // ...
        return true;
    }
}
```

To use the AsyncTask, create an instance suppling required parameters to the constructor and the call execute():

```
new AsyncHttpPostTask("http://example.com/post", httpPostParams, otherValue).execute();
```