# Enabling and update progressbar from a thread

Tags: android

Progressbar will not show when I try to access it from a thread nor update the progress. I would prefer to just have a progress spinner be displayed until the network activity is complete, and this network activity is just to post some text data to the server.This is the code I have so far, any help is appreciated thanks,

```
 Thread th = new Thread(){
        public void run() {

                     try {
                        sleep(5000);

                         while(cnt < 5000){
                             activty.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
                                 public void run()
                                 {
                                     ProgressBar pd = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
                                    pd.setVisibility(0);
                                    pd.setMax(100);

                                     pd.setProgress(cnt);
                                    cnt += 100;
                                 }
                             });
                         }
                     } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
        }

        int cnt = 100;
    };
    th.start();
    `
```

Comment: Did u check the xml?, maybe other views didn't left space enough for the progressbar.

Comment: Good eye there too, I might have overlooked that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is exactly the case where you would want to use [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html), which processes data in a separate thread and contains methods `publishProgress` and `onProgressUpdate` to update your UI on the UI thread.

The [Processes and Threads Guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html#AsyncTask) has an example of how to implement an AsyncTask as well.

Comment: Is there a way to make a generic asynctask class or will i have to make one for each network activity i have to carry out in my activity.

Comment: @kabuto178 Try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14253421/how-one-interface-can-be-used-for-different-background-android-tasks/14376233#14376233, you can change the code in doInBackground based on your request, i.e get or post

Comment: @kabuto178 - `AsyncTask`'s doInBackground can take in parameters so for example if the only difference is the file you need to download, you could pass that into your AsyncTask and reuse it: `new NetworkAsyncTask().execute(urlToDownload)` for example

Comment: One task needs a bitmap returned and the other needs JSONObject in my case

Comment: @kabuto178 - then it sounds like two AsyncTasks seem more appropriate.