# AsyncTask operation with return type

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-asynctask

I am new to android developing, as a part of my learning, I am making a multilingual news reader application, where the application is fetching rss feeds from google news and parses.

for this, I am using tabbed view for showing multiple languages, user can swipe through different language. application contains Hindi,Malayalam,English, and Tamil tabs, all lists particular news items.

each language view page is separate fragment. and there are totally four fragments is there in the application and main activity holds all these.

for all these fragments I have one AsyncTask extended class, which loads and parses news from the server.and returns an array list on its doInBackground method, but the problem with this is when I swiping from one tab to another it works very slow. I am pasting my code down. I think my AsyncTask usage is not correct, because I am showing a progress bar in onPreExecute method, but it also not showing in proper.

please anyone look on to my code and help me to correct

**EnglishNewsFragment.java**

```
    @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> newsWrapper;
            context = getActivity();
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.english_news_fragment, container, false);
            NewsLoader newsLoader = new NewsLoader(context, language);
            newsLoader.execute();
            try {

                newsWrapper = newsLoader.get();

            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                showNews(newsWrapper);
            }
            return rootView;
        }
```

**NewsLoader**

```
public class NewsLoader extends AsyncTask{

    public NewsLoader(Context context, String language) {

            this.context = context;
            this.language = language;

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {

            startDialogue();
            initAll(language);
        }


        @Override
        protected ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> doInBackground(Void... params) {
                       getNews();
                news = processXML();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return news;
        }


        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> aVoid) {
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
            stopDialogue();
        }
}
```

**UPDATE**

AsyncTask.get() blocks the UI. so that I have to implement a call back interface, can anyone help me to do it I have read a little from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14253421/how-one-interface-can-be-used-for-different-background-android-tasks/14376233#14376233) but how will be its calling and how do I pass the result to MainActivity ?

Screen shot

[image]

Comment: BTW: calling `super.onPostExecute()` and `super.onPreExecute()` is useless as there's no default implementation in super class

Comment: Why you didn't use onProgressUpdate to update your progress bar?

Comment: bcs I am not updating the progress, showing just a spinner, and it is enough

Comment: can you post showNews() in your fragment and initAll() in AsyncTask methods

Comment: Here's a very good example of AsyncTask usage - http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBackgroundProcessing/article.html#concurrency_asynchtask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have got the answer.

I have made a callback interface for passing the result to Fragment

```
public interface CallBackReciever {

    public void recieveData(ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> result);

}
```

and implemented this interface with fragment.

then passed a context of this interface to *AsyncTask*. and in its *onPostExecute()* method invoked *recieveData()* method

**Fragment**

```
@Override
    public void recieveData(ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> result) {
        newsWrapper = result;
        showNewsOnUI();
    }
```

**AsyncTask**

```
public class NewsLoader extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>>{

public NewsLoader(CallBackReciever callBackReciever) {
        this.callBackReciever = callBackReciever;
    }
 @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        startDialogue();

    }
    @Override
    protected ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> doInBackground(Void... params) {
        initAll(language);
        result = processNews()
        return result;
}
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> result) {
        stopDialogue();
        callBackReciever.recieveData(result);
    }
}
```

Comment: Interesting answer! Since the final result is an ArrayList of texts, could you use a non-UI thread like Thread and Handler? I don't see much of UI processing in the NewsLoader. Of course you know better. Congratulations!

Comment: @TheOriginalAndroid in my doInBackground() method there is a method called processNews() which fetches news from internet and returns the parsed xml. so that AsyncTask in mandatory.

Comment: Even with that job, it does not involve the UI. So maybe you can use the Thread class with Runnable?

Answer (score 1):

The `Asynctask.get()` method blocks the UI until `doInBackground()` finished.  You can use instead the `onPostExecute()` to deliver result back on the UI.

Comment: Can yu explain with an help of example or any link ?

Comment: Sorry i havent a specific link but there are some tutorial on the net about android background processing.

Answer (score 1):

The slowdown or bottleneck in the UI is probably coming from `onPreExecute`() or `onPostExecute`(). Add code like `Log.d`() and print the timing difference to see which code causes the bottleneck. For example, code `initAll(language)` may be moved to the non-UI thread of `doInBackground`(). Perhaps that method is slow.  Basically with `onPreExecute` and `onPostExecute`, be quick in whatever needs to be done.

I think you don't need to call `super.onPreExecute()` or `super.onPostExecute(aVoid)`. Google's sample does not do so or suggest to @ [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html). Maybe that causes the bottleneck also.

Hope that helps...